# Image media upload problem in page editing modus?

Tags: images, media-library

I can't figure this out, uploading an image when i am editing or adding a page doesn't work correctly. During upload i get a http error. Debugging shows async-upload.php gives a 500.
The funny thing is the image is uploaded. When i refresh the page and hit "add media" i can see the image in the library, but without the important "meta" data as ATTACHMENT DISPLAY SETTINGS >> size. And i notice size should be defined for the gallery to work properly.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Errors 500 typically require looking through server logs to discover actual issue. Have you asked your hosting support (if you have any) to take a look?

Comment: @rarst, i have multiple WP websites running on this server. The other ones don't have this issue

Comment: oh i notice when i make the images smaller in dimensions and doesn't give a http error?

Comment: seems images must be < 800px is this a new image upload setting?